# Is the Autolayout best approach for building the iOS Application?

Tags: ios, autoresize

I have built an app which supports only for iPhone (portrait),but as we know autolayout are very powerful layout tool and these are excellent, and those would be the best places to learn more.
But as per my experience ,recently in my  app using autoresizing ,I am been abled  to finishing up every screen 5 times faster than if I use autolayout for the same and it fits to all iPhone devices (3.5 inches,4 inches,4.7 inches,5.5inches).So it really saves my time.So should we  go for autoresizing instead of autolayout if our application deals with only for  iphone(portrait ) or iPad (portrait) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move to Auto-layout ASAP.

Since you said it took you less than 5 times as compare to Auto-resizing. The reason is you have not figured out the Power of it yet.

With the introduction of `Size-class` and now `Stack Views`, the power has increased much. So it is not just Auto-layout. Its a combination of 3 super tools. Learning takes some time, and is purely based upon trial and error method.

Comment: OK ...then why does Xcode 8 introduce autoresizing,autolayout and size classes in same nib file ?

Comment: Auto-resizing is part of iOS Layout setup it wont go. More option added up now!